# php code not updating database record

Tags: php, mysql

I am doing a basic inventory system I was trying to edit and update record by clicking on edit button which pass the id to the process file through the url, there I pic the id and I was able to change and update the data, now the problem is the product category, before it was appearing in just a text box and I have to type the new product to replace the old one but this could make spelling or other mistakes, to avoid that I am trying to have drop down list which is loading products from database and I will choose the new one to replace but it's not working, process file picking the id from html file and query I have checked also it's working fine but data is not being updated.

```
 <html>

       <form name="form" action="edit_record.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">        

          <select name="pro_update" class="formTxtInputmany">        
             Product Name: <option>SELECT PRODUCT</option>                
             <?php 
             $sql = "SELECT pro_id,pro_name FROM products ORDER BY pro_name ASC";
             $query = $conn->query($sql);
             $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
             $arrlength = count($result);

               for ($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++){?>            
                    <option value="<?php echo $result[$x]['pro_id'].','.$result[$x]['pro_name']; ?>">
                      <?php echo $result[$x]['pro_name']; ?>
                   </option><?php 
               } ?>  

          </select>
          <input type="submit" value="UPDATE THE RECORD">
       </form>        
</html>

    // process file     

       <?php

       if(isset($_POST['pro_update'])){    
          $pro_update = $_POST['pro_update'];

          if ($pro_update == "SELECT PRODUCT"){        
               echo "please choose producct";        
          }else{        

            $values = explode(',', $pro_update);

            $pro_id = (int)$values[0];
            $pro_update = $values[1];

            $updateQuery = "UPDATE products SET pro_name = $pro_update
            WHERE pro_id = $pro_id";
            $query = $conn->prepare($updateQuery);
           $query->execute(array($pro_update));  

          }    
       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using prepare but not actualy preparing your query.In using prepare you must use placehoders in your query, you might need to use something like this

```
 $updateQuery = "UPDATE products SET pro_name = :proname
    WHERE pro_id = :pro_id";
    $query = $conn->prepare($updateQuery);
    $query->execute(array(':pro_update'=>$pro_update,':pro_id'=>$pro_id));
```

since there are two types of place holders the named and the positional placehodler(?) . You may also use something like this

```
 $updateQuery = "UPDATE products SET pro_name = ?
        WHERE pro_id = ?";
        $query = $conn->prepare($updateQuery);
        $query->execute(array($pro_update,$pro_id));
```

Comment: do you have any error? have you tried echoing your $prod_id variable?

Comment: IT WORKS NOW THANKS, i just didn't refresh i think

Comment: im glad to hear that :D

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
$query->execute();
```

instead of

```
$query->execute(array($pro_update));
```

EDIT

Use single quotes for string & also use `trim();` for $id

```
$updateQuery = "UPDATE products SET pro_name = $pro_update
    WHERE pro_id = '$pro_id'";
```

Also

```
$pro_id = (int)trim($values[0]);
```

Comment: these variable have values they echo fine

Answer (score 0):

```
$updateQuery = "UPDATE products SET pro_name = :proupdate WHERE pro_id = :proid";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($updateQuery);
$stmt->bindParam(':proupdate', $pro_update);
$stmt->bindParam(':proid', $pro_id);
$stmt->execute();
```

You are nearly there, but this is the better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Your $updateQuery will be evaluate like this:
UPDATE products SET pro_name = {string} WHERE pro_id = {int}
which is invalid sql statement because {string} has to be quoted 'string'.

If you are using prepare statement, try to use it the right way: using bindParam (PDO) or bind_param (mysqli) to using your variable in your sql query. This has 2 benefits:
1. You dont have to worry about quoted string, escape character for harmful sql injection
2. Use your prepared query multiple times with different value in need

Regards,